# How do I describe a character tripping but regaining their balance?

Tags: characters, technique, novel, structure, description

In the story, my protagonist is walking in a part of town that is not taken care of. My character, at this point in time, is super tired and trips over a clump of grass growing from the sidewalk.

Comment: We can all identify with tripping and regaining our balance. Merely state it: "He tripped on the clump of grass, but regained his balance without injuring his dignity."

Answer (score 1):

Mary was exhausted, walking the sidewalk to the bus stop. She didn't even like this part of town, the ratty stores, the broken curbs. It looked -- Suddenly something blocked her foot in mid-stride, she lurched and regained her balance. Looking back, she'd tripped over a clump of grass growing through a crack in the sidewalk.

*Great, the perfect ending to this day, a faceplant on a filthy sidewalk.*

She'd laugh if she weren't so tired.